# How to get the related data from the child table using Entity Framework in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Below is my table structure which is related via foreign key constraints

```
CREATE TABLE "EMPLOYER_TYPE" 
(   
    "ID" NUMBER(5, 0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CODE" NVARCHAR2(5), 
    "DESCRIPTION" NVARCHAR2(150),
    "IS_ACTIVE" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 1
);
       
CREATE TABLE "EMPLOYER_TYPE_DETAILS" 
(   
    "ID" NUMBER(10,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EMPLOYER_TYPE_ID" NUMBER(5,0), 
    "EMPLOYER_COMPANY_NAME" NVARCHAR2(100), 
    "EMPLOYER_CONTACT" NVARCHAR2(20), 
    "ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION" NVARCHAR2(100), 
    "IS_ACTIVE" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 1, 
    "EMPLOYER_CITY" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 

    CONSTRAINT "EMPLOYER_TYPE_DETAILS_EMPLOYER_TYPE_FK" 
        FOREIGN KEY ("EMPLOYER_TYPE_ID")
            REFERENCES "EMPLOYER_TYPE" ("ID") ENABLE
);
       
CREATE TABLE "EMPLOYER_SOLUTION_DETAIL" 
(   
    "ID" NUMBER(19,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PROPOSAL_ID" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "EMPLOYER_TYPE_ID" NUMBER(5,0), 
    "EMPLOYER_TYPE_DETAIL_ID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "EMPLOYER_NUMBER" NUMBER(10,0), 
         
    CONSTRAINT "EMPLOYER_SOLUTION_DETAIL_EMPLOYER_TYPE" 
        FOREIGN KEY ("EMPLOYER_TYPE_ID")
            REFERENCES "EMPLOYER_TYPE" ("ID") ENABLE, 
    CONSTRAINT "EMPLOYER_SOLUTION_DETAIL_EMPLOYER_TYPE_DETAILS" 
        FOREIGN KEY ("EMPLOYER_TYPE_DETAIL_ID")
            REFERENCES "EMPLOYER_TYPE_DETAILS" ("ID") ENABLE
);
```

I am using ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework and to get the required result

```
return await context.EmployerSolutionDetails
                    .ThenInclude(s => s.EmployerType)
                    // here I need to include EmployerTypeDetails also
                   .AsSplitQuery()
                   .IgnoreAutoIncludes()
                   .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Here `EmployerSolutionDetails` has two child tables `EmployerType` and `EmployerTypeDetails`. I am able to get the data from `EmployerType`. How would I include employer type details table data also?

I am using ASP.NET Core

Comment: Was this answer helpful, could you share the progress of the issue so we could investigate more deeply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use another “Include” since the tables you need don’t contain multiple levels.

```
var X = await _context.EMPLOYER_SOLUTION_DETAIL
        .Include(S => S.EMPLOYER_TYPE_DETAILS)
        .Include(A => A.EMPLOYER_TYPE)
        .AsSplitQuery()
        .IgnoreAutoIncludes()
        .ToListAsync();

foreach (var ESD in X)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ESD.ID);
    Console.WriteLine(ESD.EMPLOYER_TYPE_DETAILS.ID);
    Console.WriteLine(ESD.EMPLOYER_TYPE.ID);
}
```

The value is acquired and the sql formated is here.

[image]

Since you can get the data of EmployerType, you know how to create the relationships between models. In case, here is the document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-one